# Intersection of two "parametrized" subsets of the rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given four fractions in fully reduced form $\frac ab, \frac cd, \frac ef, \frac gh$ we define the sets

$$A := \frac ab + \frac cd \mathbb Z, \qquad B := \frac ef + \frac gh \mathbb Z.$$

Is it somehow possible express $A \cap B$ in a similar way?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta = \operatorname{lcm}(b,d,f,h)$. Then

Then there exists integers $b',d',f',$ and $h'$ such that

- $b'=\dfrac{\Delta}{b}$
- $d'=\dfrac{\Delta}{d}$
- $f'=\dfrac{\Delta}{f}$
- $h'=\dfrac{\Delta}{h}$
- $\dfrac ab + \dfrac cdu = \dfrac{ab' + cd'u}{\Delta}$
- $\dfrac ef + \dfrac ghv = \dfrac{ef' + gh'v}{\Delta}$

So there exists integers $\hat a, \hat c, \hat e, \hat g$ such that

- $A = \dfrac 1\Delta \{\hat a + \hat cu\ : u \in \mathbb Z \}$
- $B = \dfrac 1\Delta \{\hat e + \hat gv\ : v \in \mathbb Z \}$

So we may as well examine the integer-member sets

- $\hat A = \{\hat a + \hat cu\ : u \in \mathbb Z \}$
- $\hat B = \{\hat e + \hat gv\ : v \in \mathbb Z \}$

In particular, what does $\hat A \cap \hat B$ look like?

\begin{align}
    \hat a + \hat cu\ &= \hat e + \hat gv \\
    \hat cu - \hat gv &= \hat e - \hat a \tag 1\\
\end{align}

Equation $(1)$ has a solution if and only if 
$$\gcd(\hat c, \hat g) \mid \hat e - \hat a \tag 2$$ 
If $(u_0, v_0)$ is a particular solution, then, the general solution $(u,v)$ is of the form 
$u = u_0 + t\dfrac{\hat g}{\gcd(\hat c, \hat g)}$ and
$v = v_0 - t\dfrac{\hat c}{\gcd(\hat c, \hat g)}$

Hence the members of $\hat A \cap \hat B$ are of the form

\begin{array}{c}
    \hat a + \hat cu\\
    \hat a +
    \hat c\left(u_0 + t\dfrac{\hat g}{\gcd(\hat c, \hat g)} \right)\\
    (\hat a + \hat cu_0) + 
    t \dfrac{\hat c \hat g}{\gcd(\hat c, \hat g)}\\
\end{array}

So we have proved the following theorem.

THEOREM. Let
$A = \left\{ 
   \dfrac ab + \dfrac cdu :
   u \in \mathbb Z
  \right \}$ and
$B = \left\{ 
   \dfrac ef + \dfrac ghv :
   v \in \mathbb Z
  \right \}$

Define the following integers

- $\Delta = \operatorname{lcm}(b,d,f,h)$
- $\hat a = \dfrac ab\Delta$
- $\hat c = \dfrac cd\Delta$
- $\hat e = \dfrac ef\Delta$
- $\hat g = \dfrac gh\Delta$

Then $A \cap B$ is a non empty set if and only if
$\gcd(\hat c, \hat g) \mid \hat e - \hat a$. When this is true,

$A \cap B = 
    \dfrac 1\Delta \left \{
    n + t \dfrac{\hat c \hat g}{\gcd(\hat c, \hat g)}
    : t \in \mathbb Z
    \right\}$

Where $n$ is any particular solution to the equation
$n = \hat a + \hat cu\ = \hat e + \hat gv$.